# Ruby On Rails Heroku APP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, git, heroku

I am working on Ruby On Rails Shopify App deployed on Heroku. Suddenly error occured "uninitialized class variable @@storage in ShopifySessionRepository". I was unable to trace this.I rollback the code to previously deployed code and app worked. But now, the code which i have is with errors. So i cannot push any more code to heroku. And i cant even access the code which is working(previous code). I dont how to get out of this situation now. I am new to git, heroku and ruby on rails.Is there any way, i can access the working code using git or anything else. If not, what this error message is "uninitialized class variable @@storage in ShopifySessionRepository" and why it occurred?

I am using rails 4.0.2

Comment: Without code to look at, stack traces to look at etc, we won't be able to know who or what broke your code...  Why can't you push to Heroku?  What error does that give you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue occurred because the the version of the shopify gem was automatically upgraded while pushing the code to heroku. Because no version was specified in the gem file for this gem, it was upgraded. The file ShopifySessionRepository was not present in the earlier version of the gem file. This was added in the latest version. 
I added the older version of the gem in the gem file like this
gem 'shopify_app','~> 4.4.4'

and it worked. Now i don't know that my code was not compatible with the latest version of the gem or there is any bug in the latest version. But degrading the version solved the issue.

Comment: Weird. Just had this error, downgraded, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The bug is fixed in the current version of the `shopify_app` gem, 5.0.0

Comment: i tried to use the latest version of shopify_app gem but again it gives error "Cannot use InMemorySessionStore in a Production environment" . After some debugging we found that again it was related to 'sessionRepository'. So i again downgraded and it worked. Is this a bug or we need to implement it differently??